# Error #1009 when jumping to the next frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting a TypeError: Error #1009 when jumping to the next frame.

This code is in frame 3:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,activate);


function activate(event:Event)
{
  if (fname.length > 2 && sname.length > 2 && cname.length > 1)
  {
    bt_Send.alpha = 1.0;
    bt_Send.enabled = true;
    enableIt = true;
  }
  else
  {
    bt_Send.alpha = 0.05;
    bt_Send.enabled = false;
    enableIt = false;
   }
}
```

When I click the "next" button, the movie jumps to frame 4. After the button is clicked appears the TypeError: Error #1009 at new_cics_fla::MainTimeline/activate()

In the frame 4 are no mention to the function "activate".

The movie runs normally, but I'd like to know why I'm getting this message.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers, Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `enterFrame` is continuing to execute but the properties the `activate` method acts on are not available in the frame you've sent the playhead to.

Try removing the `enterFrame` in the method which handles clicks on your next button:

```
function nextClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // Clean up the enterFrame
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,activate);

    // Now advance to the next frame
    this.gotoAndPlay(4);
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm! THANKS **net.uk.sweet**. You are very kind.